# How to POST an xml file to ServiceStack with IRequiresRequestStream

Tags: xml, servicestack

Having read a couple of different [SO Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493594) and the [Docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization) on this subject, I'm still confused and unable to get past the RequestBindingException on my service endpoint. For example, I'd like to POST the following xml to the service with POSTMAN.

```
<LeadApplications>
  <LeadApplication>
    <Email>daffy.duck@example.com</Email>
    <FirstName>Joey</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>Disney</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Duck</LastName>
    <Street1>1 Disneyland Street</Street1>
    <Street2>2 Disneyland Street</Street2>
    <City>PAUMA VALLEY</City>
    <State>CA</State>   
    <Zip>92503</Zip>
  </LeadApplication>
</LeadInformations>

[Restrict(RequestAttributes.Xml)]
public class LeadData : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}

public object Post(ServiceModel.Types.DirectApi.Legacy.LeadData request)
{
    return null;
}

Routes.Add<ServiceModel.Types.DirectApi.Legacy.LeadData>("/Leads/LeadData/", "POST", "LMS - DirectApi")
```

I had hope this would be the best way to overcome the .NET deserialization property ordering issues.

Raw Request /Response

```
POST http://localhost/LO.Leads.Receiver/api/Leads/LeadData/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 381
Origin: chrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2289.0 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ss-pid=fhjNz7BGBBqgps6zsnUo; ss-opt=perm; X-UAId=f94092eb-fae8-4b39-b5ff-ae3b404645d8; m=34e2:|41b8:f|4a01:t|ca3:t|b12:f|47ba:t|77cb:t

<LeadApplications>
  <LeadApplication>
    <Email>daffy.duck@example.com</Email>
    <FirstName>Joey</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>Disney</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Duck</LastName>
    <Street1>1 Disneyland Street</Street1>
    <Street2>2 Disneyland Street</Street2>
    <City>PAUMA VALLEY</City>
    <State>CA</State>   
    <Zip>92503</Zip>
  </LeadApplication>
</LeadApplications>

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["6f4255ee84fa45d1a2e05de8a268fc37","a52523648aed4dfaae96e607d07b5163","f9cf295e8e7b4aa1b0579929e61d59a5","7b4daa97fc8d427cb952b17414c4da31","707e7624fa4546c3911a9cb3ce5e6a36"]
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 28 Jan 2015 02:19:30 GMT
Content-Length: 538

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ErrorResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types"><ResponseStatus><ErrorCode>RequestBindingException</ErrorCode><Message>Unable to bind request</Message><StackTrace>   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequest(IRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath)
   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, String operationName)</StackTrace><Errors i:nil="true" /></ResponseStatus></ErrorResponse>
```

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: Can you also include the Raw HTTP Request/Response that you're using to POST this XML, please enable `DebugMode=true` so it also includes the StackTrace.

Comment: OK, added the request/response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue where since the Request Content-Type matched an existing registered Serializer (i.e. XML) that it would still attempt to deserialize the body using that Serializer. It's now fixed to ignore all Serializers for `IRequiresRequestStream` requests [from this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/c62566993e11a685ee06e9b5e80d92bc7dfda61b).

Which lets you now create access the stream and read it to normal XML with:

```
[Restrict(RequestAttributes.Xml)]
[Route("/Leads/LeadData/", "POST", Notes = "LMS - DirectApi")]
public class CustomXml : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}

public class RawRequestService : IService
{
    public object Any(CustomXml request)
    {
        var xml = request.RequestStream.ReadFully().FromUtf8Bytes();
        return xml;
    }
}
```

Which you can call with [HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils), e.g:

```
var xml = @"<LeadApplications>
                <LeadApplication>
                <Email>daffy.duck@example.com</Email>
                <FirstName>Joey</FirstName>
                <MiddleName>Disney</MiddleName>
                <LastName>Duck</LastName>
                <Street1>1 Disneyland Street</Street1>
                <Street2>2 Disneyland Street</Street2>
                <City>PAUMA VALLEY</City>
                <State>CA</State>   
                <Zip>92503</Zip>
                </LeadApplication>
            </LeadApplications>";

var requestUrl = Config.ServiceStackBaseUri + "/Leads/LeadData/";
var responseXml = requestUrl.PostXmlToUrl(xml);

Assert.That(responseXml, Is.EqualTo(xml));
```

This change is available from **v4.0.37+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet). It would also work before if you changed the request to use a different Content-Type, e.g. `application/xml-lead` which doesn't match any existing Serializers, but then you'll need to remove `[Restrict]` which is only permitting XML requests.